# Symfony - Query Builder with Join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

i am a bit confused, why this is not working.

I have two Entities, one entity called user and one entity called shed. 
1 user can have many sheds and 1 shed can belong to 1 user.

they are connected with a ManyToOne

```
class User
{

 /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) NOT NULL")
 */
protected $active = true;


 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Shed", mappedBy="user")
  */
  protected $shed;
}

class Shed
{
     /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="shed")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *
 * @var User
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) NOT NULL")
 */
protected $published = false;
}
```

What i want to achieve is, that i query the newest 3 sheds from active users that are published.

In my ShedRepository i have the following method:

```
class ShedRepository
{
    public function getNewestSheds()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->join('AppBundle:User', 'u')
            ->andWhere('u.active = 1')
            ->andWhere('s.published = 1')
            ->orderBy('s.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(3)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
      }
}
```

When the shed.published property is 0 the shed is not shown. if the shed is published but user is inactive the shed is shown too, but shouldnt. 
Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct annotation for `active` attribute should be:

```
 /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) NOT NULL")
 */
```

(you forgot to specify name and type of the column, which made the attribute not mapped and therefore it was always true)

Analogic with published attribute of Shed entity.

**EDIT (Correct answer) :**

you have wrong join() call. You need to use: `->join('s.user', 'u')`

Comment: thats not true, 
you can use columnDefinitions to specify the column too. 
and the attribut has a default value set to false :) 
Either though, your changes doesn't solve my prob :(

Comment: try to use `TRUE` instead of `1` in where conditions, for example: `->andWhere('u.active = TRUE')`

Comment: tried so, doesnt change the result i dont know whats wrong, the published constraint is working but the active not :(

Comment: 1. is the query working in controller (not in custom repository), 2. is the generated SQL correct (check in log) ?

Comment: The builded SQL Statement seems to be wrong. 

I am getting:

INNER JOIN user u1_ ON (s0_.published = 1 AND u1_.active = 1) ORDER BY s0_.created_at DESC LIMIT 3"
but the first ON should be without published. Seems like he is using the where conditions as ON Statement

Comment: Oh i was blind, you have wrong join() call. You need to use: `->join('s.user', 'u')`

Comment: Dude, you are a genius :) this works perfectly :) Cheers for your help. Can you post your answer as a new comment so i can mark it as correct? :)